# 'Undefined' parameters in function calls in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, syntax, tkinter

Whenever I program something in python with `Tkinter`, the code looks like this:

```
    from Tkinter import *

    class GUI():

        def __init__(self, master):

            self.master = master # master is an instance of Tk
            self.master.title("") # set the name of the window

            self.frame = Frame(self.master, width=800, height=500, bg="#eeeeee")
            # 800, 500 and "#eeeeee" are examples of course
            self.frame.pack()

            self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, width=800, height=500, bg="ffffff")
            self.canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
            #mostly there are some other widgets

        # here are obviously other methods

    def main():

        root = Tk()
        app = GUI(root) # root and app.master are synonyms now
        app.master.mainloop()

    if __name__ == '__main__':

        main()
```

My problem is, I don't really understand why `Frame(width=800, height=500)` or `place(x=0, y=0)` is working: I didn't define the parameters `height`, `width`, `x` and `y`. Looking at the code in the `Tkinter` - module, the functions expect a paramter called `*args` or `**kw`. I know how to use them (at least well enough to develop some small applications), but I don't know how to define a function which uses this parameters. I feel like I don't know really much about this part of python, though I can work with it.

So my Question is:

how can I define a function, what is called with the following Syntax:

```
functionName(parameterName1 = value, paramterName2 = value, ...)
```

I don't need to know how to make a function what accepts a varying amount of parameters (combined with my problem), but it would be fine too.

Comment: Any basic python tutorial shows you how to do this. Here is [Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) in the standard tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to are called *keyword arguments*.

Arguably one of the best ways to define a function with specific keyword arguments is to provide defaults. It's common for the default to be `None` if you don't have the need for any other default:

```
def functionName(parameterName1=None, parameterName2=None):
    print("parameter one is: %s" % str(parameterName1))
    print("parameter two is: %s" % str(parameterName2))
```

You can then call this function like so:

```
foo = functionName(parameterName1="hello", parameterName2="world")
```

You can also do what tkinter functions do, and accept `**kwargs` as a parameter. This gathers up all named arguments into a dictionary that you can then iterate over:

```
def functionName(**kwargs):
    print("the arguments are:", kwargs)
```

Note: you don't have to use the name `kwargs` -- you can use any name you want (`**kw`, `**kwargs`, `**whatever`), but `kwargs` seems to be the most common.

Comment: Thanks, I already knew how to set a default value, I just didn't know that I can type the arguments name in the function call.